# How to add delimitedtext Layer via Python in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a problem to add a *.tab file as delimitedtext layer in QGIS 3.

```py
uri = ("file:///{}?"
               "&delimiter={}"
               "&xField={}"
               "&yField={}"
               "&crs={}"
               "&decimal").format(tab_text,
                                        "\t",
                                        "Rechtswert",
                                        "Hochwert",
                                        "EPSG:31468",",")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer", "delimitedtext")
```

If I test the layer with `.isValid` I get a False. Did I have to name more variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add add another backslash when specifying tabs:

```
"\\t"
```

Comment: Thats not working because my delimiter is a tab. If I try double backslash i get "\t" as delimiter

Comment: @RickJames - Yes, a single slash is shown for me in the layer's information but to import it, I had to use double slashes. Tested on QGIS 3.0.1 for Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: you are right it worked. The other problem was my coordinate system.

Comment: @RickJames - Glad it worked :)

Comment: Why the need to use \\t as oppose to \t.